# Failure installing Pillow on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: django, pip, python-imaging-library

i tried installing pillow on my ubuntu 14.04, i get the following error message. 
Should I install it with easy_install? because I've heard the pip doesn't work that much. please any suggestions? 
Or is there I need to install prior to running the command

> pip install pillow

```
  running egg_info

writing dependency_links to Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

writing requirements to Pillow.egg-info/requires.txt

writing Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



reading manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'

warning: no files found matching '*.sh'

no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'

warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'

warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'

warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'

warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis'

warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis/*'

warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'

warning: no previously-included files found matching 'build_children.sh'

warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'

warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution

writing manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

running build_ext





The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,

a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.



Please see the install instructions at:

   https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/media/mohit/mohit1/1.8/matchmaker/build/pillow/setup.py", line 756, in <module>

    raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)

__main__.RequiredDependencyException:



The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,

a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.



Please see the install instructions at:

   https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
```

Comment: i think the error is about zlib  library not installed

sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev

Comment: Install ALL dependencies described in: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: i did, but i get an error
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Answer (score 0):

try this,

`sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev`

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library) Pillow is packaged as *python-pil* and *python3-pil* in Ubuntu 13.04 and later.

To install the Python Imaging Library in Ubuntu 14.04 and later, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python-pil # for python 2.X
```

and/or...

```
sudo apt install python3-pil # for python 3.X
```

Run this command if the imageTk import doesn't work:

```
sudo apt install python3-pil.imagetk # for Python 2.X replace `python3-` with `python-`
```